# How to access specific data inside a JSON file on an Angular project

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I've been trying to work with this JSON file

```
[
    [
        {
            "category": "Bags",
            "productData": [
                {
                    "id": 1000,
                    "name": "Trolley backpack",
                    "short description": "short description",
                    "long description": "LONG DESCRIPTION",
                    "image": "../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/trolleyBackpack.png"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productData": [
                {
                    "id": 1001,
                    "name": "Laptop bag",
                    "short description": "short description",
                    "long description": "LONG DESCRIPTION",
                    "image": "../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/laptopBag.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "category": "Eco",
            "productData": [
                {
                    "id": 1100,
                    "name": "Bamboo Pen drive",
                    "short description": "short description",
                    "long description": "LONG DESCRIPTION",
                    "image": "../../assets/images/catalogue/eco/bamboo-pendrive.png"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productData": [
                {
                    "id": 1101,
                    "name": "Bamboo tabletop items",
                    "short description": "short description",
                    "long description": "LONG DESCRIPTION",
                    "image": "../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/bamboo-tabletop.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I created a service and used http.get. Then, in my app.component.ts I subscribed to the data with

```
 Productinfo: any = []


  constructor(private service: DataStorageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  
    this.service.GetProductDetails().subscribe(data => {
      this.Productinfo = data;
    })

  }
```

I haven't been able to access this data in the app.component.html though

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-sm-4 g-5">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3" *ngFor="let products of Productinfo.productData">
          <div
          class="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-white bg-white rounded-5 shadow-lg" *ngIf="">
          <img src="{{products.image}}" style="object-fit: cover;">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column ps-3 pe-5 fontName text-light text-shadow-1 h-100"
          style="position: absolute;">
          <h2 class="pt-5 mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold"
          style="position: relative;">
            {{products.name}}
          </h2>
            <img
            src="../../../assets/images/bonjour-logo.png"
            alt="Logo"
            width="32"
            height="32"
            class="rounded-circle border border-dark bg-dark"
            style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;"
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This solution with `Productinfo.productData` doesn't seem to work. Should I access the productData array in my TS file?

I would also like to be able to display data conditionally as well, based on category. I would assume that *ngIf is the way to go here, but I am unsure. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: The data you've pasted is an array with array items?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON contains an array, with another array inside, which has objects with the fields "category" and "productData". Therefore, you should first loop over the array that contains the objects. Then, once you have the list of objects with the aforementioned fields, you can use a for loop to iterate over the list of productData. I think you'll need interfaces to achieve this.

```
[ <- First here with a for loop
        [ <- Then you loop this, so you can get into the object
            {
                "category": "Bags",
                "productData": [ <- inside of each object, you need to loop this in order to show productData object
                    {
                        "id": 1000,
                        "name": "Trolley backpack",
                        "short description": "short description",
                        "long description": "LONG DESCRIPTION",
                        "image": "image.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the JSON stracture:

```
 [{
  "category":"Bags",
  "productData":[
     {
        "id":1000,
        "name":"Trolley backpack",
        "short description":"short description",
        "long description":"LONG DESCRIPTION",
        "image":"../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/trolleyBackpack.png"
     },
     {
        "id":1001,
        "name":"Laptop bag",
        "short description":"short description",
        "long description":"LONG DESCRIPTION",
        "image":"../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/laptopBag.png"
     }
  ]},{
  "category":"Eco",
  "productData":[
     {
        "id":1100,
        "name":"Bamboo Pen drive",
        "short description":"short description",
        "long description":"LONG DESCRIPTION",
        "image":"../../assets/images/catalogue/eco/bamboo-pendrive.png"
     },
     {
        "id":1101,
        "name":"Bamboo tabletop items",
        "short description":"short description",
        "long description":"LONG DESCRIPTION",
        "image":"../../assets/images/catalogue/bags/bamboo-tabletop.png"
     }
  ]}]
```

I think this is stracture you expects to.